# MySQL Error Message: Subquery Returns More than 1 Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Would you help me to fix this, please:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT AES_DECRYPT(cryptoword, SHA2('DatabaseEncryption1', 512)) FROM file_tree) AS cryptoword1,
  (SELECT AES_DECRYPT(name, SHA2(cryptoword1, 512)) FROM file_tree) AS name;
```

As the topic says, I get error saying that my **subquery returns more than 1 row**. What I look for to achieve is:

1. Get the cryptoword for the particular database record.
2. Use that cryptoword to decrypt the rest of the record.
3. Repeat the process for all the table records/multiple records satisfying WHERE condition, which I can add later

My query works, if I use the query for one record only. However, I need to get multiple records within from the table. Every record has its own cryptoword, which is different per each row. My task is therefore to get the cryptoword for particular record, and to use that one to decrypt the rest of the record. I need to repeat this process for all the table records.

Because of performance reasons, it all needs to be formatted within one query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say *for the particular database record* yet you aren't filtering your results at all. You need a `WHERE` clause on both of your subqueries which will guarantee that only 1 record is returned.

Comment: or `LIMIT 1` at the end of each query to tell mysql to return only 1 row

Comment: I see what you mean. The challenge is, that I would need to apply my subquery for the whole table.

Comment: @MatBailie, great comment. This was my goal initially. However, while decrypting *name* in your query, *cryptoword1* was not recognize. At least MySql has refused such query. Hmm, maybe I had done a mistake anywhere and have overlooked it?

Comment: Why don't you just do it with php in the mix?

Comment: @CodeBird, good question. In PHP it would be perfectly doable. However, because of performance reasons, I need to decode and return many records quickly. PHP would slow everything down.

Comment: ok go for a stored procedure then, I don't see any other solution. Going into too complicated queries with too many nested query will slow things down too

Comment: @CodeBird - Nesting queries is not *in and of it self* a performance drain.  Badly written nested queries that obfuscate indexes are a performance drain.  But any badly written SQL, nested or not, is a performance drain.

Comment: @MatBailie you're right, but I guess for a situation like that, I wouldn't hit my head against the wall trying to nest queries to make the main query run (and it will surely take some more processing... not drain, but more processing) if I can create a procedure that can do it.

Comment: @CodeBird - No, it won't take more processing.  In my example below the optimisation engine will parse it, create a plan and then execute the plan.  Just because the SQL is nested doesn't mean that the plan is nested in some way.  SQL just allows you to express certain logic, and sometimes that logic requires nested expressions; that nesting is completely unrelated to the amount of processing power consumed when running the plan.  Only if the query yields a highly complex or high cost plan will more processing power be used, and that is *not* a function of nesting.

Comment: @matbailie ok you convinced me... Nice logic in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work out the value of `cryptoword1` in a sub-query, then you can reuse the result to work out the value of `name` in the outer query.

```
SELECT
  cryptoword1,
  AES_DECRYPT(name, SHA2(cryptoword1, 512))   AS name
FROM
(
  SELECT
    AES_DECRYPT(cryptoword, SHA2('DatabaseEncryption1', 512)) AS cryptoword1,
    name
  FROM
    file_tree
)
  AS sub_query
```

Comment: I have answered your commend below my question above. It looks that your initial suggestion has disappeared? Have you found a mistake in there? I would prefer what you suggested initially.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori - My comment didn't notice that you needed to re-use the result of `cryptoword1`'s calculation in another field.  As you have discovered, that result doesn't exist at that point; you don't control calculation order, it is treated as if they are calculated in parallel.  This means that you can *not* do `SELECT f(x, y) AS a, f(z, a) AS b FROM table`.   You either need a sub-query, as in this answer, or you need to repeat yourself in your code; `SELECT f(x, y) AS a, f(z, f(x, y)) AS b FROM table`.  However, even MySQL should optimise this SQL to avoid redundant effort.

Comment: Yes, the second, repeated solution works. I have tested it already. But it makes no sense to re-generate my cryptoword1 every time per record column, as I have multiple columns in the table. I believe the solution proposed in this answer above will work. I am testing it now.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori - You're making the assumption that writing `SELECT f(x, y) AS a, f(z, f(x, y)) AS b FROM table` *will* cause `f(x, y)` to be calculated twice; most optimisers will see the repetition and reuse the value internally - SQL is effectively compiled and different RDBMS do lesser or better jobs than others.  That said, it is still repetition of code which is often best avoided. The two answers *should* perform the same, it depends on your perspective as to which is more readable, maintainable, etc.

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you very much. You are getting the *accepted answer*. However, may I ask for a bit explanation on this your query, please? What confuses me the most is: `AES_DECRYPT(cryptoword, SHA2('DatabaseEncryption1', 512)) AS cryptoword1, name`. What is `name` doing in the `FROM` section of the subquery, please?

Comment: Additionally, may I rely on the optimization capabilities of MySQL engine? If I go in the `SELECT f(x, y) AS a, f(z, f(x, y)) AS b FROM table` way, I assume that the column values will not be repeatedly decrypted. Am I not on the safer side, if I design my query so, that I do not have to rely on the MySQL to optimize my queries?

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori - If by *safer* you mean *guaranteed a certain behaviour*, then being explicit is always safer, yes; you don't run in to changes if you install a patch, for example.  And the reason `name` is mentioned in the inner query, is because you use it in the outer query; the outer query knows nothing about the inner query except for the fields it *explicitly* selects.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in the select statement must evaluate to a single value, or else you will get this error. This makes sense since you are looking to fill the value for one field.

Comment: How does this answer the question though? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: @Yuck, hi Yuck. I have updated my question. I need to repeat the subquery for all the records within the table. I hope, the update will make my question better to comprehend.